# PowerShell Script that counts the files and folders in a number of servers then exports output to a CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm generating a PowerShell script which takes in a list of remote servers and counts all the files and folders on each drive of each server in said list. It seems the code to count the files and export to csv may be off.

Below is the current iteration of the script I have developed:

```cs
#variable used to call the list of R servers
$ServerList = 'H:\R_SERVER_COUNT\AllServerNames.txt'

# Loops through all the servers on list
foreach ($server in Get-Content $ServerList) {
    $count = Get-ChildItem -r "$server\"

    $fcount = Get-WmiObject Win32-LogicalDisk -ComputerName '$server' |
              Select-Object @{Label="Server";Expression={$_.SystemName}},
                  @{Label="Drive";Expression={$_.DeviceID}},
                  @{Label="Files";Expression={($count | ? {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false}).Count}},
                  @{Label="Folders";Expression={($count | ? {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true}).Count}}
    $folderAndFileCount += $fcount
}

#creates a csv file and places it into folder
$folderAndFileCount |
    Export-Csv 'H:/R_SERVER_COUNT/FolderAndFileCount.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

What I expect is to a CSV file that provides server name, the name of the drive, the file count and the folder count.
At present I get `ï»¿`.

Comment: `Get-WmiObject Win32-LogicalDisk -ComputerName '$server'` -> `Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $server`

Comment: Use double quotes in `… -ComputerName "$server"` as single quotes in ´'$server'´ results to a computer name `$server` (literally `$server`). In any case, direct query of `Win32-LogicalDisk` could take _very long_ time…

Comment: Also, `Get-ChildItem -r "$server\"` probably won't do what you think it does. If `$server` is the hostname or FQDN of the server try `Get-ChildItem -r "\\$server\C$"` instead to enumerate the files on drive C:. A somewhat better approach would be to use `Invoke-Command` to run the code on the remote computer that enumerates the computer's drives, counts the files/folders, and returns only the respective counts. However, beware that either way enumerating all files/folders on all drives of a computer is going to be excruciatingly slow.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, how would one go about calling all drives on the remote server, not just drive C:?

Comment: You could use `Get-PSDrive` or WMI for that.

Comment: @RoonDog - are you aware just how SLOW `Get-ChildItem` is with large numbers of files - and that it leaves out a fair number of them? [*grin*] for my `C:\` drive, robocopy [set to /L list only] took **_9 seconds_** & reported d=49,914 & f=304,122  ///// gci took 12 minutes & reported d=41,243 & f=249,957 ///// windows explorer took 1 minute & reported d=49,862 & f=304,129 ///// you may want to use robocopy and parse the job summary. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

while i think robocopy likely would be a better solution [it's usually at least an order of magnitude faster], this will do the job. note that i have `-Recurse` commented out while testing. you will need to re-enable that for the real thing. [*grin*]

this uses `Invoke-Command` to run on the target systems *in parallel*. it ignores non-responding systems, but if you need them you can get the names by comparing the input list with the responders.

you will also likely want to use `Select-Object` to remove the usually-unwanted properties added by `Invoke-Command` [PSComputerName, RunspaceID, etc ...].

```
#requires -RunAsAdministrator

$ComputerNameList = @'
LocalHost
10.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
BetterNotBeThere
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

$IC_ScriptBlock = {
    $DriveList = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider 'FileSystem' |
        # exclude read-only devices such as ROM drives
        Where-Object {$_.Free -gt 0}

    foreach ($DL_Item in $DriveList)
        {
        $GCI_Params = @{
            LiteralPath = $DL_Item.Root
            # while testing, leave the "-Recurse" paramter out
            #Recurse =  $True
            ErrorAction = 'SilentlyContinue'
            Force = $True
            }
        $DF_Info = Get-ChildItem @GCI_Params
        $DirInfo = $DF_Info.Where({$_.PsIsContainer})
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            SystemName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
            Drive = $DL_Item.Root.Trim('\')
            DirCount = $DirInfo.Count
            FileCount = $DF_Info.Count - $DirInfo.Count
            }
        }
    }
$IC_Params = @{
    ComputerName = $ComputerNameList
    ScriptBlock = $IC_ScriptBlock
    ErrorAction = 'SilentlyContinue'
    }
$RespondingSystems = Invoke-Command @IC_Params

$RespondingSystems
```

one drive from one system ...

```
SystemName     : [MySysName]
Drive          : C:
DirCount       : 13
FileCount      : 3
PSComputerName : LocalHost
RunspaceId     : 0c67f714-ae8a-4831-b647-b27bd73ce94d
```